# Laravel & relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am building a web app using Laravel (5.7). At some point, the user must input his **location** that is comprised of:

- Country
- State
- City

So for this, I created 4 tables:

### **Countries table:**

**Columns**: id, name

**Relations**: hasMany states

### **States table:**

**Columns**: id, country_id, name

**Relations**: hasMany cities, belongsTo country

### **Cities table:**

**Columns**: id, state_id , name

**Relations**: hasMany Locations, belongsTo state

### **Locations table:**

**Columns**: id, city_id, name

**Relations**: belongsTo City

My questions are:

1) Is this the correct approach?

2) Obviously, there are countries out there without the "state" segmentation. If this is the case, how are we going to move up to the Country (using relationships) when the state is not present?

3) How do we know the minimum Eloquent relationships we can use on each model? Because a country also has a lot of cities. Do we use this relationship as well, or is it OK because states has a lot of cities?

I would be very happy if someone helped me clear this out. Its been bothering me for quite some time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, question 2 in itself answers that this isn't the correct approach, right?    A city probably should belong to a country as well as a state since states may not be relevant.   Without knowing any details about your app, maintaining a database of all cities in the world will prove difficult.

Comment: State has many Cities, City belongs to Country potentially. So to get the country you can go $location->city->country. To get the state you could use isset. I would also consider 'State/County' as I see on many sites, in the same way you could have 'postcodes/zipcodes'.

Comment: This sounds like polymorphic relationships, where a state could be considered the same as a territory or province in another country.

Comment: @Devon The app is really simple. I need to create a Location (name, country, state (if any), city, address) and then assign it to a company. A company can have multiple locations (a.k.a offices around the world). By the way, the countries/states/cities will be very limited and they will be added manually by the backend administrator. I eventually want to be in a position to filter locations based on their country/state/city (hence the relationships). Thanks